# Could not install MyEclipse 7.1

Tags: installation, java, myeclipse

I am trying to install MyEclipse 7.1 but I get the following error message:

```
"Could not create folder "C:\Documents and Settings\myPcName\Settings\Temp;C:". The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect."
```

I am really confused by these error because i don't have any idea why is happening... it should be a simple install process...

On my pc I am also running an Eclipse 3.2 version... should i uninstall it ? I could not found it on Add/Remove programs.

I also installed jre 1.6 and the sane jdk.

Please if you have an idea about this, give me a hand...

Comment: This isn't really a programming related question. Perhaps this should be moved to superuser?

Comment: Hi, 

Thanks for the message... yes you are right... i just asked.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You won't find it in add/install programs. Find the folder where you have eclipse installed and delete the entire folder. Thats what I did for mine. And then install it again.